# How to fix Gradle errors about API level, androd.enableR8, and resource linking failed?

Tags: unity, build-process, export, build

I encountered several errors when building on Unity 2021 for Android Platform. They're all part of the same "error group" so I'll list all of them down here since they're all part of a single problem which is exporting a game for Android. I can't find a single solution since everything I'm listing is part of my solution.

Here are some of the errors I've encountered:

1. In Google Play Console, "You cannot use API level 30 and below. For security reasons, your app should use API level 31+"
2. In Unity, "android.enableR8 is deprecated"
3. In Unity, unityLibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
4. In Unity, "Gradle Build Failed. Android resource linking failed... AAPT: error: attribute android:export not found"
5. In Unity, "Gradle Build Failed. Android resource linking failed..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### "You cannot use API level 30 and below"

You just need to set the API level to 31+ in `Edit/Project Settings/Player/Other Settings/Identification/Target API Level`
[image]

### android.enableR8

[Google](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity-arf/android-12-build) made breaking changes with how Unity builds the Android projects. The solution is to download a gradle that is v6.1.1+ and below v7 in https://gradle.org/releases/. This [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efzqmYqyJsM) explains it clearly. I'll list down the things he did to get his project working. Note: His steps didn't work for me; hence, the succeeding solutions may help you.

1. Download gradle from [link](https://gradle.org/releases/) whose version is greater than or equal to 6.1.1 and less than 7.0.0. (why not below 6.1.1, because Unity said so.)(why not 7+, see section below). Extract it to a folder. Copy the folder path. The folder path should contain the `lib` folder which Unity will be needing.
2. In `Edit/Preferences/External Tools`, untick the gradle checkbox and paste the folder path to your gradle you've extracted.
   [image: external tools]
3. In `Edit/Project Settings/Player/Publishing Tools`, check these 5 items.
   [image: check these]
4. Add `android:export="true"` in the first Activity tag in `Assets\Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml`. (In my case, this didn't work but, for some, it worked for them. Just try doing it first)
5. In `Assets\Plugins\Android\baseProjectTemplate.gradle`, make sure the version in this line is `4.0.1`.

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```

6. In `Assets\Plugins\Android\gradleTemplate.properties`, comment out the `android.enableR8` by placing a `#` at the start of the line.
7. Attempt to build.

If not working, proceed to next section.

### unityLibrary:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

1. Make sure you downloaded a gradle between 6.1.1 and the last version before it becomes 7. Here's a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606085/unitylibrarycompiledebugjavawithjavac)
2. Attempt to build. If not working, proceed to next step.

### AAPT: error: attribute android:export not found

1. Remove `android:export=true` in the first Activity tag in `Assets\Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml`
2. Attempt to build. For me, the Unity project was already able to export the game.

### Gradle Build Failed. Android resource linking failed...

1. If still not working, see below content which is from [here](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408584314388-Why-is-Android-resource-linking-failing-#:%7E:text=This%20error%20stems%20from%20the,page%20of%20the%20Unity%20Editor.&text=See%20AdMob%27s%20guide%20on%20Unity,meet%20the%20requirements%20for%20AdMob.)
   [image: part 1]

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

2. Another solution is to go to the Editor folder in your project, create a file called `AndroidManifestPostGenerateGradleProject.cs`, and then paste the following script into it:

```cs
{
    public void OnPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject(string path)
    {
        Debug.Log("Build path : " + path);
        string gradlePropertiesFile = path + "/../gradle.properties";
        if (File.Exists(gradlePropertiesFile)) File.Delete(gradlePropertiesFile);

        StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(gradlePropertiesFile);
        writer.WriteLine("android.useAndroidX=true");
        writer.WriteLine("android.enableJetifier=true");
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

3. If there's still a problem, see [conversation](https://forum.unity.com/threads/gradle-build-failed-android-resource-linking-failed.605806/) regarding unicode characters

These are pretty much my research over the past week. Hopefully, this helps some devs.

Comment: will accept my answer in 2 days

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was in Target Level API.

By default API 34 was set.

After changing it to API 33 gradle built my project.

Probably the root cause is API 34 in beta at this moment.

Hope this will help if you are strugging a whole day like I am.